# Bootstrap javascript needing to reload, or not functioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

**Issue 1:** My navbar toggle menu will not close, but will open, unless I remove either of the following from my layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Now, when i remove this the toggle works and will open and close.  Although, my sign-in modal will not function without it.

**or:**

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Issue 2:**

I have accordions that will not work on first load - but will then work once the page has been reloaded.

**My navbar in summary:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Navbar</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">

   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     #more nav items code here
     <li class="nav-item-2 nav-display-2">
       <button type="button" class="btn ripple-effect btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtnSignIn2">Sign Up/Login</button>
       <div class="modal fade" id="SignInModal2" role="dialog">
         <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
           <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
               <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
              </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
      </li>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtnSignIn").click(function(){
        $("#SignInModal").modal();
    });
});

</script>
```

**accordion code:**

```
<a class="collapsed card-link text-center" id="edit-accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFIRST">

      </a>
      <div id="collapseFIRST" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">

          </div>
      </div>
```

**application.js:**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets

//= require jquery

//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
```

Is there any you see standing out in my code wrong?

Comment: Update, if I remove //= require jquery3 and only keep //= require jquery, both the toggle, and the modal work!. although, vice versa, (no //= require jquery, and yes to //= require jquery3), it won't work. Although, I still have my issue with the accordion not opening without a reload

Comment: In your browser, open web console and type this, make sure you have bootstrap 4:  `$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION`  also check `jQuery.fn.jquery` make sure version >= 3

Comment: its is 4.3.1 and 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Add the bootstrap gem to your Gemfile and remove the html tag from the layout

Gemifle

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.3.1'
```

You should not have 2 versions of jQuery.

Then run `bundle install`

Then change this to:

```
/= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Also in hour applications.scss you should have

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Also in layout try instead:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': true %>
```

Comment: I guess I should had mentioned i had bootstrap installed correctly.. but i changed the order of the application file to yours and no difference in the functioning of everything

Comment: I really want to figure this our without needing to hack this with pure javascript and simply use the bootstrap but i tried without the html files in either combination possible, same issues.

Comment: Update, if I remove `//= require jquery3` and only keep `//= require jquery`, both the toggle, and the modal work!.  although, vice versa, (no //= require jquery, and yes to //= require jquery3), it won't work.   Although, I still have my issue with the accordion not opening without a reload

Comment: did you change the order as I described?  trubolinks and tree should be last, order matters here.

Comment: I did try that but same issue.  My gemfile is this: `gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.3.1'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'


gem 'sprockets'

`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your script. It is explained [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks)

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $("#myBtnSignIn").click(function(){
    $("#SignInModal").modal();
  });
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't help.  Without having the html bootstrap line tag, it won't work (the modal), but the toggle will only work when its gone.  I am not sure what the issue is here.